# How to print an URL in a c# #error preprocessor in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I'm writing on some Unity modules.

Some of them depend on each other so I want to print out an error including the URL where to get the missing module(s).

I tried this:

```
#if !THIS_MODULE
#define THIS_MODULE
#endif

#if !REQUIRED_MODULE
#error This Module requires the RequiredModule module
#error Please get it from "https://example.com"
#endif
```

If the required module is missing the first line just prints out in the Unity3D console as expected

```
error CS1029: #error: 'This Module requires the RequiredModule module'
```

but the second line only prints

```
error CS1029: #error: 'Please get it from "https:'
```

---

- I tried it with and without `"` and `'`

  this din't change anything but adding the `"` or `'` to the ouput
- I tried it like

  ```
  #error Please get it from "https:\/\/example.com"
  ```

  but than it printed

  ```
  #error: 'Please get it from "https:\/\/example.com"'
  ```

---

**How can I print an URL corrctly using the `#error` preprocessor in Unity?**

Is there any escaping rule I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any escaping at all. ([Online demo](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAxAUwE7oPboAQAUJUBDAZ1VwHNVhcxaAzbAW1wCIALYYAB1JAD0A1AA9izHkQB0AYyzM2AWABQQA).)

The message for an `#error`/`#warning` directive is (basically) anything after the directive and before the end of the line.
This behaviour is also [documented in the compiler source](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Parser/DirectiveParser.cs#L255).

Comment: And yet .. it doesn't work as I said in my question. Is it possible that Unity itself escapes something there?

Comment: Might be. I'm not very familiar with the Unity compiler. But I don't know why they would change the error directive parser, of all places.

Comment: Hm I can Just print it out in the Unity console if using `Debug.Log(string)` but it cuts it off in the preprocessor

Comment: Well it is possible that Unity did it on purpose to prevent someone to place spam or malicious URLs inside of precompiled `.dll`s. There would be no chance to avoid displaying them in the editor so maybe they decided to simply not allow to show urls. Thanks anyway for your help! I can see the error displayed correctly within VisualStudio so it has to be something about Unity.